# rsync general question

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use rsync.

At first, everything looks very good:

```
rsync -Pniahv -e ssh /home/xxx/Videos/ root@192.168.2.222:"/shares/Public/Shared\ Videos/" --stats

...
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah.avi
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah S01E01 
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah - S01E02
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah - S01E03 
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah - S01E04
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah - S01E05 
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah - S01E06 
<f+++++++++ Serien/blah - S01E07
...

Number of files: 232
Number of files transferred: 223
Total file size: 118.24G bytes
Total transferred file size: 117.51G bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 9.46K
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 10.18K
Total bytes received: 712
```

After that, i copied some of the files manually and runned rsync again in dry mode:

```
rsync -Pniahv -e ssh /home/xxx/Videos/ root@192.168.2.222:"/shares/Public/Shared\ Videos/" --stats

...
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah.avi
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah S01E01 
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah - S01E02
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah - S01E03 
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah - S01E04
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah - S01E05 
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah - S01E06 
<f..tpo.... Serien/blah - S01E07
...
Number of files: 232
Number of files transferred: 223
Total file size: 118.24G bytes
Total transferred file size: 117.51G bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 9.46K
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 10.18K
Total bytes received: 712
```

Why hasn't changed something in the --stats, although only the permissions and the timestamp have to be updated and not the full files need to be copied?

Comment: can you edit your question and provide the actual output you'd like us to see rather than providing links?  Also, if the files didn't change then they didn't change so nothing to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not certain, but I believe when you are in dry-run mode no files will be inspected by the delta-transfer algorithm to see if they should be excluded.  Since you are in dry-run mode you won't see any differences in the bytes sent/received.

Answer (score 0):

the `-n` option means no data was saved in the destination.  so, the second time was just like the first time.